# Difficulties trying to understand ruby's precedence rules

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
a=[]

a << 4 && a[0]+=1 && a[0]+=1 if a==[]

puts a.inspect

output [9]
```

I'm new in ruby and I was just trying things out.

I want to know what operations are being perfomed to get this result and in what order.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You might find it easier to start with smaller examples and building up your understanding inductively...

Comment: I'm sorry, somebody change my title, I want to know what exactley is the computer doing, what operations and the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to vastly simplify your example. I'm guessing your confused about why you get `9`, instead of `6` (4+1+1). It's all because of `&&` precedence being higher than `+`.

Here's a simplified version of your code.

```
a = 4
a += 1 && a += 1
puts a.inspect #=> 9
```

What's happening is that your `&&` is binding first, then the `+` operation is binding after. Which means that your code is actually more like this:

```
a = 4
a += (1 && a += 1)
puts a.inspect #=> 9
```

If you add parenthesis yourself, you get more what you might expect.

```
a = 4
(a += 1) && (a += 1)
puts a.inspect #=> 6
```

Really though, you would never use `&&` like this, as you don't always get what you would expect...

---

The other tricky thing, that `if` statement is shorthand. It's the same as this:

```
if a == []
  a << 4 && a[0]+=1 && a[0]+=1
end
```